# How to calculate the continuous price of a bonding curve token

Tags: solidity, bonding-curves

I am trying to write a solidity smart contract implementing a power bonding cure like y=mx<sup>n</sup>

where `y`=token price, `m`=slope parameter, `n`=exponential parameter, and `x`=token supply.

Assuming `m` would be 0.003, reserve ratio `r` is 1/3, and `n` is 2:
How do I get the price of tokens when a user wants to buy or sell `k` amount of tokens?

Here is what I came up with but it does not come close to solving the problem

```
function calculatePurchaseReturn(
        uint256 _totalSupply,
        uint256 _depositAmount
    ) public pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 newTotal = _totalSupply.add(_depositAmount);
        uint256 newPrice = (30 * ((newTotal * newTotal) / DECIMALS)) / 10000;

        return newPrice;
    }
```

**Edit**

I have looked at the [bancor bonding](https://yos.io/2018/11/10/bonding-curves/) curve but I don't want to use their power function. I wan't to be able to do the calculation on my own so I can also do the same calculation outside of solidity just incase I need to. My issue right now is how to implement the continuous token price and how to get the price at any given time.

Thanks

Comment: Does this help https://yos.io/2018/11/10/bonding-curves/ ?

Comment: I have looked at that article, but I don't want to use the power function. I am trying to implement it on my own so I understand what happens behind the scene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assumption, given the total supply of token `x`, the price `y` is given by:
[image]
with `n`, `m` constants.

Now, the cost `dp` to buy `dx` tokens is `y*dx`. So, if we want to buy `k` tokens starting from a total supply of `x`, the total cost is:

[image]

Inverting the formula we get `k` as a function of the cost `p`:

[image]

with Rb = m*x^(n+1)/(n+1) "reserve balance", and r = 1/(n+1) "reserve ratio".

This is what we are interested in, basically how many tokens we buy by paying `p`, i.e. the "purchase return".

Using `n = 2` we can rewrite it easily like this:

[image]

and in solidity:

```
    function calculatePurchaseReturn(
        uint256 _totalSupply,
        uint256 _depositAmount
    ) public pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 temp = 1000*_depositAmount + _totalSupply*_totalSupply*_totalSupply;
        temp = powerOneThird(temp); // temp^(1/3)
        
        return temp - _totalSupply;
    }
```

You can't escape doing the `1/3` exponentiation. The Bancor's formula is a good general one, and it helps preventing overflows.

Comment: thank you for your response. Why did you multiply `_depositAmount` by 10000? In my code my calculation was done in bps that was why I divided by 10000, what does 10000 represent?

Comment: @Starbody my bad, it's a `1000` since `m=3/1000`

Comment: What does 1000 represent?

Comment: @Starbody Just a factor, `m=0.003=3/1000` so `3*p/m = 1000*p`

Comment: @0xSanson, ¿why don't use the constant product curve ? `xy = m` ---> `y = m (x ^ -1)` I thought this formula was used in the AMMs.

Comment: @Jose4Linux That's a different kind of AMM (the one used by UniswapV2). There are also other AMMs, like `y*x^3+x*y^3=k`, used for stable tokens. Generally the bonding curve model is used when you want to price a token based on how much it was minted already.

Comment: Thanks, @0xSanson !! I would like to know more about that. I read this article yesterday, https://yos.io/2018/11/10/bonding-curves. Iit only talks about the formula used by Bancor. Do you have any learning resource about those bonding curves ?

Comment: @Jose4Linux There aren't many articles about this. Just by googling I found these which may be ok: https://phemex.com/academy/what-is-bonding-curve https://www.linumlabs.com/articles/bonding-curves-the-what-why-and-shapes-behind-it